# Problem when the second time create peerconeection WebRTC ( A sender already exists for the track.), any idea should I handle

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I'm using react, socket.io and webRTC.The first connection is great but the next time has the problem I think this issue on SDP is not refreshed. I already call close() peer-connection.

Error code:

> InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'addTrack' on 'RTCPeerConnection': A sender already exists for the track.

My **initCall** function was called in **useEffect**.

```js
let configRTC = { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };

let localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configRTC);
let remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configRTC);
const initCall(stream,loca)=>{
socket.on('other-users', (socketId) => {
    console.log('other user');
    conn = localConnection;
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => localConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
    localConnection.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
      candidate && socket.emit('candidate', { socketId, candidate });
    };

    // Receive stream from remote client and add to remote video area
    localConnection.ontrack = ({ streams: [stream] }) => {
      if (!remoteVideo.current) return;
      remoteVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
    };
    
      localConnection
        .createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1, iceRestart: true })
        .then((offer) => localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => {
          socket.emit('offer', { socketId, description: localConnection.localDescription});
        });
   
socket.on('offer', (data) => {
    // Ininit peer connection
    console.log('offer', data.socketId);
    console.log('des', data.description);
    // remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configRTC);
    conn = remoteConnection;
    console.log('remote', remoteConnection.signalingState);
    console.log('remoteTRICKLE', remoteConnection.iceGatheringState);
    remoteConnection.onnegotiationneeded = (event) => {
      try {
        console.log(remoteConnection.signalingState);
        console.log(this.remoteConnection.signalingState);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };

    conn = remoteConnection;
    remoteConnection.restartIce();

    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => remoteConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

    remoteConnection.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
      candidate && socket.emit('candidate', { socketId: data.socketId, candidate });
    };

    // Receive stream from remote client and add to remote video area
    remoteConnection.ontrack = ({ streams: [stream] }) => {
      remoteVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
    };
      remoteConnection
        .setRemoteDescription(data.description)
        .then(async () => await remoteConnection.createAnswer())
        .then(async (answer) => await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer))

        .then(() => {
          console.log('answer', data.socketId);
          console.log('answerDes', remoteConnection.localDescription);

          socket.emit('answer', { socketId: data.socketId, description: remoteConnection.localDescription });
        });
   
    }
  });

  socket.on('answer', (data) => {
      let description = new RTCSessionDescription(data.description);
      localConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
  });


  socket.on('candidate', (candidate) => {
    let can = new RTCIceCandidate(candidate);
    conn.addIceCandidate(can);
  });
  return;
};
```

Comment: This problem happen because I forgot to close( unsubscribe) socket `socket.off('candidate') socket.off('offer') ...` when unmount component. Thank everyone.

Comment: - Another potential problem for others: \
In React, in StrictMode, `useEffect` will be executed twice. \
- To manually remove the tracks (I think): \
`for (const rtcRtpSender of pc.getSenders()) {     pc.removeTrack(rtcRtpSender);   }`

Answer (score 0):

You simply retry to add the same MediaStreamTrack to the same Peerconnection who already own it.
ex :

```
var medias = null;
var rc = null;
var p = new RTCPeerConnection();
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then((res)=> {
          medias = res;
          p.addTrack(medias.getTracks()[0])
          p.addTrack(medias.getTracks()[0]) // throw Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addTrack' on 'RTCPeerConnection': A sender already exists for the track.
      });
```